# What does 'bottle :unneeded' do?

Tags: homebrew

I read [Method: Formula.bottle](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/Homebrew/brew/Formula.bottle) but it's not very clear to me. When writing a home-brew formula, what does the following do?

```
bottle :unneeded
```

Comment: It tells it, per the document you linked, that the formula *"should not be bottled & can be installed without any compile required"*. It's very difficult to know what *"not very clear"* means, precisely.

Comment: Why do people insert it in to their formula?
https://github.com/callahanrts/homebrew-dbmgr/blob/ea6264eb7b8bdc763c3010901591da8c4c5ba970/dbmgr.rb
Whats the benefit to end users?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When a formula you submitted is accepted in one of the official taps, a bot grabs it; builds a pre-compiled version of the formula, and uploads it in some public location. This pre-compiled package is called a bottle and is used to speed-up installation of compiled things.

`bottle :unneeded` is an indication to the bot that this formula doesn’t need a bottle; e.g. because there’s nothing to compile.

Note that `bottle :unneeded` was deprecated by `homebrew-core` [in June 2021](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/pull/11239), and no longer has any meaning to the bottler.